# Linux drop packets if received from another equipment

Tags: linux, tcp

**Problem description** :

When I establish a VPN connexion between a VPN client and my home server, if the connexion are both across my firewall (pfSense) or are established directly, the connexion is OK.

But if the VPN client establish a connexion directly to the home server, and the response going across my firewall pfSense, the VPN server doesn't route the packet from the LAN interface (eth0) to the VPN interface (tun0).

Do you know Why ?

---

**1st Example OK** : *with a both direct connexion* :

Go : VPN Client => VPN Server => Home Server

Return : Home Server => VPN Server => VPN Client

---

**2nd Example OK** : *with both connexion accros firewall (pfSense)* :

Go  : VPN Client => VPN Server => Firewall pfSense => Home Server

Return : Home Server => Firewall pfSense => VPN Server => VPN Client

---

**3rd Example NOT OK** : *with a direct connexion for the start, and accros firewall (pfSense) for the back* :

Go : VPN Client => VPN Server => Home Server

Return : Home Server => Firewall pfSense => VPN Server => VPN Client

---

**IP List :**

Home Server : 192.168.100.50

Firewall pfSense : 192.168.100.20

VPN Server : 192.168.100.40 (interface : eth0) and 10.8.0.1 (interface : tun0)

VPN Client : 10.8.0.6

---

**Note** : In the 1st and 2nd example, when I execute a tcpdump, I see the return packets on the eth0 and on the tun0. But in the 3rd, I don't see the return packets on the tun0 but only in the eth0.

**Hypothesis** : *It is like if the packets were dropped if they come back from a different equipement.*

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved !

Simply add a "Floating Rule". In this rule, select "none" in "State type".

"none" is a system which : "Do not use state mechanisms to keep track. This is only useful if you're doing advanced queuing in certain situations. Please check the documentation."

In fact, pfSense dropped the packets because it didn't receive a "SYN" flag before. It is a basic problem and common when the network follows an asymmetric route.